# ParseExact DateTime error

Tags: c#, datetime, datetime-format

I have a list of DateTime as strings: dd.MM.yyyy H:mm:ss (The time is 24 hours format but the hour is single digit: `6` instead of `06`)

- 14.12.2016 6:20:21
- 15.12.2016 8:30:00
- 16.12.2016 12:30:00
- 17.12.2016 14:33:00
- 18.12.2016 18:10:00

I am trying to parse exact the string values as a DateTime object like this:

`DateTime.ParseExact(dt, "dd.MM.yyyy H:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` (dt is the string value from the list)

The problem is I get an error saying the string is not a valid DateTime ...

With the current format, the first and second values in the list work fine, when it get's to the third 'boooom' I get the error.

Am I missing something in my format?

Comment: Have you tried `HH`?

Comment: @Tim:  Yeap, with `HH`, the first value get error and third will work

Comment: @Tim looking at the code if he were to try `HH` it will work for 3 out of the 4 dates because the `HH` portion of this line `14.12.2016 6:20:21` expects the time to be `2 digits` if it were 14.12.2016 06:20:21`, it would not fail..

Comment: Works in [ideOne](http://ideone.com/JAWDJg).  Are you certain the input is exactly what you've posted? Where are the dates coming from? Can you show the actual code?

Comment: It's very strange, your format is correct and I have no problem with it on your sample data. `HH` will not work as it requires two digits with leading zero.

Comment: I put together a [.Net Fiddle] with your exact input and it works: https://dotnetfiddle.net/OgzXYz. Is there something else going on?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the overload of [DateTime.ParseExact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/332de853(v=vs.110).aspx) that accepts an array of valid formats:

```
string[] formats = { "dd.MM.yyyy H:mm:ss", "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss" };
var result = DateTime.ParseExact(dt, formats, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 0);
```

**UPDATE:** As others have noted, `H` should match both one-digit and two-digit hours, so something else is going on. The following code runs successfully on my system (.NET 4.5.2):

```
string dt = "16.12.2016 12:30:00";
var result = DateTime.ParseExact(dt, "dd.MM.yyyy H:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: `H` should accept hours 0 to 23 inclusive, so this might just be covering up a different problem.

Comment: See my comment on the OP about the original input seemingly working in isolation.

Comment: It's just workaround for strange bug. Original format template is correct and should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had to parse exact the using Hour, Minute, and Second then use the `ToString` method to convert to a Month, day, and year format

```
  $myStringDate=[Datetime]::ParseExact($item.myDateObject,'MM/dd/yyyy H:mm:ss',$null).ToString('MM/dd/yyyy')
```